# Laravel Sanctum - sanctum/csrf-cookie (204 "No content")

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

Laravel sanctum has been a bit of a headache for me as i have spent hours trying to figure out why `sanctum/csrf-cookie` route returns no content. initially the same route return 404 not found but after adding `'prefix' => 'api/sanctum'` **config/sanctum.php** it seems to work except that it outputs nothing and no cookie is set in my browser.

**Here are some of my codes**

**.env**

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080
SPA_URL=http://localhost:8080
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

**--config/cors.php**

```php
'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'register',
        'user/password',
        'forgot-password',
        'reset-password',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
        'user/profile-information',
        'email/verification-notification',
      ],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**axios**

```js
export const authClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  withCredentials: true, // required to handle the CSRF token
});
```

and having done all of that, if i tried to generate a token using

```js
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
    // Login...
});
```

i get `204 no content` response
i have also added the api middleware in kernel.php as instructed in the [doucmentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication)  but still wont set the cookie. and when i try to make request to another route protected by sanctum i `419 token mismatch`.
i have also run a fresh installation of laravel, `php artisan optimize`, cleared my brower history, checked the endpoints in postman but still thesame `204 and 419` exceptions

Comment: What is your VUE_APP_API_URL, is it http://localhost:8000?

Answer (score 7):

I was struggling with the same issue for days and then founded a way that worked.
so :

The `'/sanctum/csrf-cookie'` route return a 204 response when successfull, the  then you have to send your `post` request with credentials. i used to get a 419 reponse status.

so after followed laravel docs here is what i added :

1. SPA
   make sure you set the `withCredentials` header to `true`
2. API

.env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN='.localhost'
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='localhost,127.0.0.1'
```

.kernel.php

add in your middleware array : `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class`

Comment: It works, but needed to change '.localhost'  to 'localhost' without '.' in front.
Worked without `StartSession::class` in kernal.php api. Needed to uncomment `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` in kernal.php

Answer (score 1):

Hey I don't know whether you've found the answer or not but that request meant to have empty response body. Your CSRF token is available in the header of the response ;D

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` route by default uses the middleware group `web` as defined by `$middlewareGroups` in `\App\Http\Kernel.php`.

Make sure that this middleware group contains `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`, because this is the middleware that actually sets the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie.

If you are using a middleware group with a different name:
You can't change the middleware used by the Sanctum route at the moment, so it is probably easiest to disable the default route by adding `'routes' => false` to your `config/sanctum.php` file:

```
<?php

return [
   ...
   'routes' => false,
   ...
];
```

Then add a new route to your `routes/web.php` that doesn't have to return anything:

```
Route::get('/my/csrf', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse(null, 204);
    }

    return new Response('', 204);
});
```

You should also place this route outside of any authentication, so it can be called before login.

Answer (score 0):

From HTTP Specification:

> The HTTP 204 No Content success status response code indicates that a request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to navigate away from its current page. This might be used, for example, when implementing "save and continue editing" functionality for a wiki site.

According to specification 204 is the exptected response from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert in `bootstrap.js` file

```
import axios from 'axios';
window._ = _;


window.axios = axios;
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = "/api/";
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue in my reactjs app, I fixed this issue by sending the following

`axiosClient.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

I hope this will help.